# Prevent animation of list items on div refresh every second

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a page which lists files from database every second.

**DESIRED RESULTS**

- I want **all** the li elements to fadeIn one by one on page load.
- Then fadeIn only the **new li elements** when new files are added to the database otherwise no animation to the already listed elements.

To get the fresh list of files I am using setInterval which in turn is causing the all the list items to fadeIn one by one every second. What should I do to achieve the desired results?

**TO SUM UP WHAT I AM ASKING**

I am asking for a way to show the elements as if they are fading in on by on on page load. Then if new items are added to the database then show them only one by one with the fading effect but at that time the fading effect should not be applied to the older items.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var filelist = $('#file_list');
    $('#loading').show();

    var checkUpdate = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "generate_list.php",
            success: function (result) {
                $('#loading').hide();
                var arr = JSON.parse(result);
                console.log(arr);
                if (arr.length > 0) {
                    $('#empty_storage').hide();
                    filelist.html(arr);

                    $('li').each(function (i) {
                        $(this).delay(400*i).fadeIn(400);
                    });
                }
                else {
                    filelist.html('');
                    $('#empty_storage').show();
                }
            },
            error: function (response) {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $.alert({
                    theme: 'black',
                    title: false,
                    content: response
                });
            }
        });
        setTimeout(checkUpdate, 1700);
    };
    setTimeout(checkUpdate, 1700);
});
```

**CSS**

```
#file_list li
{
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: none;
}
```

**PHP SNIPPET**

```
// Fetching only last 10 records LIFO
    $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM uploads ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10");
    $query->execute();

    $items = array();
    while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        // Generate respective data to display
        $file_id            = $row['id'];
        $ico_path           = $base_icon_src.get_logo($row['file_ext']);
        $full_file_name     = $row['file_name'].'.'.$row['file_ext'];
        $file_ext           = $row['file_ext'];
        $file_code          = $row['file_code'];
        $download_file_path = './storage/'.$file_code.'.'.$file_ext;
        $file_size          = $row['file_size'];
        $file_upload_time   = $row['timestamps'];

        if(file_exists($download_file_path)) {
            // Generating markup
            $items[] = '<li>
                        <div class="f_icon"><img src="' . $ico_path . '"></div>
                        <div class="left_wing">
                            <div class="progressbar"></div>
                            <a class="download_link" href="#" id="'.$file_id.'"><div class="f_name">' . $full_file_name . '</div></a>
                            <div class="f_time_size">' . date("M d, Y", $file_upload_time) . '&nbsp; &#149; &nbsp;' . human_filesize($file_size) . '</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="right_wing">
                            <div class="f_delete">
                                <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#" aria-label="Delete" data-id="'.$file_id.'" data-filename="'.$full_file_name.'">
                                <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" title="Delete this?"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </li>';
        }
    }
    //content in $items must be in UTF-8
    echo json_encode($items);
```

Comment: I guess the real problem is how to get just the new elements from the database, right now you get all items again every second ?

Comment: So what should I do? Updating the question with my PHP code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general - this is the workflow you should follow:

1. On page load (first time) get the list of the files you want to preview (it can be all of them, or only the last X). Make sure you have the id (from the database) of the **last** item (the largest id, if your items are orders). We will call this `MAX_ID`.
2. Once loaded - animate them one by one.
3. Using `setTimeout`, get the "next bulk" of files (you need to pass to the php script the ID that you saved from #1, so you can get only the files where id > max_id).
4. If you got new files - add them (you can animate them one by one).
5. Update the `MAX_ID` to be the new id you got from the "new bulk".
6. Inside the `success` function you should call again (using the `setTimeout` function to the code the gets the "next bulk" (#3).

Here is a simple example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('li').hide();
  $($("li").get().reverse()).each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(400*i).fadeIn(400);
  });
});

items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
$('#a1').click(function() {
  $(items).each(function(i, val) {
    li = $('<li>').text(val).hide();
    $('#u1').prepend(li);
    li.delay(400*i).fadeIn(400);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="u1">
  <li>5</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>1</li>
</ul>

<div id="a1">Click to add more items</div>
```

Comment: Check the updated snippet, it can give you some ideas

Comment: out of curiosity, since I will be posting every second the max_Id won't it cause bandwith to exceed at a certain point?? If not what are the challenges I might face in terms of the server services?

Comment: exceed by what? if you have some limits you might get to them, however of your response is 1k, this is 60k per minute, which are ~3.6mb per hour which are ~86mb per day (if the site is open 24/h). it's not something you should really care about (unless you have tons of users, and in such case you might want to consider moving to websockets).

Comment: ok. And what if I save the max_id in a text file on the server and file_get_contents to get the max_id whenever required?

Comment: Not sure why you would want it to be saved on the server. The whole idea here is that you need that id on the client side (in the javascript). This way on the next request (from the client) - you want to pass this value and ask the server to give you only files with "newer" ids.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123800/discussion-between-ayan-and-dekel).